# How do I revoke Amazon SES SMTP rights

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

How do I revoke Amazon SES SMTP credentials? Do I just remove the SES-specific IAM user or can I revoke SMTP credentials and recreate them for the same user?

Answer (score 1):

The Amazon SES SMTP credentials are entirely derived from the access key id and secret key for an IAM user. The SMTP credentials will no longer work if you do any of the following:

- Update the policy for the user so it no longer has the SendRawEmail permission
- Delete or deactivate the access key from which the credentials are derived
- Delete the IAM user

If you want to create a new set of credentials then create a new access key for that user and follow the [documented process](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html#smtp-credentials-convert) to generate the SMTP credentials for that access key.